# How can I run Ruby code on my linux server?

Tags: ruby, linux

I have a simple GNU/Linux server that has [cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/) and [PHP](http://www.php.net/) support. How can I run Ruby code on my server? Does it work like PHP?

Comment: Ruby is a real programming language. But you can also use it for websites, e.g. with Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you are asking if Ruby runs on PHP, you need to go back to school.

Comment: @alfa So is PHP. The difference is that PHP is interpreted at runtime, not with a compiler. There exist tools to compile PHP code into a native executable that's launched on page load.

Comment: 1. Ruby is an interpreted language. 2. Compilers compile and do not interpret. 3. PHP is not a real programming language (at least for me). :D

Comment: @ColeJohnson Nope. I didn't ask that. I wonder is ruby like php? I have hosting package. When put "echo "hello";" to in a index.php and upload it to server, i can see output. So can ruby run like this?

Comment: You should really run through a couple Ruby tutorials Imrahil.

Comment: @alfa I hate PHP too, but it _is_ a programming language. If you are saying it isn't because it is interpreted, then you are saying Perl and Python aren't programming languages either.

Comment: @Imrahil your English wasn't clear enough. I reworded it based on my interpretation.

Comment: @ColeJohnson For me, a programming language is something that is usually not only used for websites. Call it general purpose language if you like. Interpreter or compiler makes no difference. As I said, Ruby is not compiled, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux? Ruby is probably already installed.

Run:

```
$ which ruby
```

To get more specifics about the ruby version do:

```
$ ruby --version
```

You run a ruby file by:

```
$ ruby some_ruby_file.rb
```

If you really do need to install go here:

```
http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/
```

If you actually need to install ruby (or would like to manage your rubies, cause the echo-system moves so quickly) you can either install:

- RVM https://rvm.io/

OR

- Rbenv https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is installed in most Linux distros. However, if you will do serious work, [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is better. Installing ruby directly is not the best idea. I suggest using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install and manage your Ruby installations, it enables more than one ruby version to run happily on the same machine. And no, it does not work like php.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ruby does not work with PHP.

Since you are using Linux, chances are that Ruby is already installed. To use on a Linux server do:

```
install ruby
```

You will also want to have some sort of version manager, like Ruby Version Manager, or RVM, to manage the version and the gems you will need for your programs.

If you don't have experience with Ruby, you should do some reading and take a couple tutorials:

Here are a couple links:

http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby

Comment: How can I do that? I have no experience about servers. To show my knowledge, i can only move wordpress files and install it.

Comment: Open a terminal in type: install ruby

Comment: I really don't know how to open terminal. Should I contact with my hosting provider to do that?

Comment: You should do some homework my friend. Sounds like you have a lot to learn. Google: how to open terminal on linux server. Not trying to be rude, but before you do ANYTHING you should really do some leg work and read up on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can open terminal in linux. But I have only ftp access informations.